# NSWorkspace launchApplication: fails for the first time with root user

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to launch one of my apps(say app2) from another of my apps(say app1) on my Mac OS X **10.7.4**. I am using the below code for the same:

```
[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] launchApplicationAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appPath] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"mode"] forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:&err];
```

This works fine except for the first time i.e. if we have a new machine, then the first attempt for launching the app2 from app1 fails when tried for the first time when logged in as root user but works fine subsequently.

Below is the error I get on dumping the NSError:

> 2012-11-05 07:47:48 +0000: The application “App2” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810).

Also, I get the below messages in "**All Messages**" in Console:

> 11/4/12 11:47:48.329 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: System: Bug: 12B19: launchd + 79534 [AEF41441-17BC-36E6-B1F8-57BADBDFEBCF]: 0x0
>
> 11/4/12 11:47:48.329 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: System: This API can only be used by a process running within an Aqua session.
>
> 11/4/12 11:47:48.329 PM App1[2405]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=5 label=[0x0-0x57057].com.ak.app1 path=/var/root/Library/Caches/com.ak.app2/app2.app/Contents/MacOS/app2 flags=0

The strange think is that it only fails for the first attempt with root user.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. The code is already posted: `[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] launchApplicationAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/var/root/Library/Caches/com.ak.app2/app2.app"] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"mode"] forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:&err];` I was getting the appPath from the argument. I have expanded it here to the actual value.

Comment: did you call this code from an app within the context of `NSApplicationMain`?

Comment: The call is very deep. my main function code: `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [ [ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];CFStringRef appPath = (CFStringRef)[ [ [ [ [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] bundlePath ] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent ] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent ] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent ] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent ];
 NSString *appType = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"AppType" ];
    
 int errorCode = 0;
 CheckForUpdate( @"mode",
     appPath,
     (CFStringRef)appType,
     &errorCode );`

Comment: How to know if I am within context of NSApplicationMain?? Thanks

Comment: given what you just pasted, you aren't.

Comment: sorry for many edits. I am new to this. The main function is posted above but its formatting is not coming good.

Comment: not sure what people are downvoting you for, the question is well-formed and the problem is real.

Comment: Please see my answer for an explanation for why this is failing, and why there's probably no way around it on newer OS's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to launch an application from a non-UI process. This is no longer supported, as it uses `LSOpenApplication` internally, which does not support non-UI processes since Lion. Please see this [discussion](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Aug/msg00196.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks @yfrancis. In discussion, it says to use per-user launchd agent. I think I am doing same: `cat ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ak.app1.plist 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>com.ak.app1</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
  <string>/Applications/App1.app/Contents/MacOS/App1</string>
  <string>auto</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
 <key>StartInterval</key>
 <integer>12600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>`

Comment: But what does this launchd plist have to do with your `launchApplicationAtURL` call? Besides, you said you were running app1 as root, now it looks like you have a launchd plist for it in your non-root user.

Comment: Ok - The plist was for launching app1 which, in turn, launched a cocoa app (app2) (Similar to comments in discussion). My app will run for all users (the problem was only coming for root user). Also, you have commented that there is probably no way for it in newer OS's. But, I need to do it. Can you please suggest something which comes close to it. Thanks a lot.