# Is it possible to open an application from an Xcode bot run script

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, applescript, appium

I am building an iOS application that has some pre-action run scripts.  More specifically, my run script is designed to open a terminal and run a command to open Appium (an automation application).  I have got this working on my local machine using the following applescript

```
set scriptPath to " test.sh" //test.sh is a script that opens appium and runs some tests
tell app "Terminal"
do script scriptPath
end tell
```

when I build and run my application on my local machine the script works just fine - it opens the terminal, which then opens appium, and kicks off my automated test.  The problem is that when I try to use a Xcode CI to make a build (and run my automation) the Terminal never opens.  I looked in console.app and the error I get is the following:

```
osascript: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=5 label=com.apple.Terminal.9008
```

After doing a lot of research and digging I am starting to wonder if this has to do with the (relatively) new restrictions apple has placed on daemons running UI applications (issue is brought up in this thread: [NSWorkspace launchApplication: fails for the first time with root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229234/nsworkspace-launchapplication-fails-for-the-first-time-with-root-user))

So, is this my issue?  Is it impossible to open a application from an Xcode bot?  If not has anyone found a way to do it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you found any ways to do this yet? For instance, the post-build triggers that were added in Xcode 6?